# Bandwidth when plotting densities in R

Tags: r

When I plot the density for wind direction using `circular` package, I get an error. The error is shown below. Can someone explain the bw (bandwidth) that I need for the amount of data?

```
plot(density(dirCir))
Error in density.circular(dirCir) : 
  argument "bw" is missing, with no default
```

This is the actual code that I have.

```
library (circular)
dir <-c(308,351,330,16,3,346,345,345,287,359,345,358,336,335,346,16,325,354,5,354,322,340,6,278,354,343,261,353,288,8) 
dirCir <- circular(dir, units ="degrees", template = "geographics")
mean(dirCir)
var(dirCir)
summary(dirCir)
plot(dirCir)
plot(density(dirCir))
rose.diag(dirCir, main = 'dir Data')
points(dirCir)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @eipi10 says, `bw` has to be explicitly chosen. Depending on the kernel that you choose large and small values of this bandwidth parameter may produce spiky density estimates as well as very smooth ones.

Common practice is to try several values and choose the one that seems to describe the data best. However, note that the following functions provide more objective ways of selecting the `bw`:

```
# bw.cv.mse.circular(dirCir)
[1] 21.32236
# bw.cv.mse.circular(dirCir, kernel = "wrappednormal")
[1] 16.97266
# bw.cv.ml.circular(dirCir)
[1] 19.71197
# bw.cv.ml.circular(dirCir, kernel = "wrappednormal")
[1] 0.2280636
# bw.nrd.circular(dirCir)
[1] 14.63382
```

Comment: Julius, based on a few examples I've just tried, if you run `density` on a circular object and use a `bw` on the order of 1 or more, you end up with almost no structure in the density distribution. Just a smooth ellipse or even a circle showing no density variation at all. On the other hand, if you run `density` on the same data before converting to a circular object, then the bandwidths suggested by the functions in your example make sense. I haven't used the `circular` package before, but it seems that bandwidth operates differently for circular objects.

Comment: Thanks @Julius. I am just a novice to R. Why is the question voted negatively? People on here assume way too often.

Comment: @Gunnerfan, I haven't downvoted your question, but there might be several reasons for that, including the one you mentioned. Your code was a bit poorly formatted but I fixed it and I don't think that was a reason; it is not entirely clear whether you ask about the error or the meaning of `bw` parameter; asking about the meaning would be more suited to stats.stackexchange, whereas a very basic idea and usage examples are given in `?density.circular`.

Comment: @eipi10, you are right that `bw` might work differently with circular objects, but it also depends on the kernel. Using `"wrappednormal"` kernel one gets bandwidths less than 1 and large ones for `"vonmises"`. I will update my answer with these examples. (Seems that there is something wrong with `bw.cv.mse.circular` using `wrappednormal` kernel).

Comment: @Julius. I did read up on it. Most of my understanding comes from viewing videos on youtube and scouring the internet. Thanks again for the rendered help. Do you suggest using the random values or going the objectively route? I did use random numbers such as this `plot(density(dirCir,bw = 60), main = "", shrink = 1.8)` and got a different density than @eipi10 did. But overall they are in the same direction. The spikeness of the distribution is not aesthetically pleasing I think.

Comment: @Gunnerfan, I would probably go the objective route. Yes, usually you want something in between spiky and flat density.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `density` on an object of class `circular`, it appears that you have to include a value for `bw` (bandwidth) explicitly (as the error message indicates). Try this:

```
plot(density(dirCir, kernel="wrappednormal", bw=0.02), ylim=c(-1,5))
```

See below for the graph. The `ylim` range is so that the plot fits inside the plot area without clipping. See the help for `density.circular` for more info on running the `density` function on `circular` objects. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks `@eipi10`, well appreciated